# Pygame starting at fullscreen and then crashing

Tags: python, sockets, pygame, udpclient

This is the shortened server code which is supposed to receive screenshot from client and then show it on pygame screen on the server side:

```
'''max_bytes = 64000
    udp_conn = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    udp_conn.bind(('0.0.0.0', 5000))
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1900, 1000))
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    while True:
        try:
            size_msg, address = udp_conn.recvfrom(max_bytes)
            size = int.from_bytes(size_msg, byteorder='big')
            while size > 10000000:  # if size is greater than 10M then loop has to fire to get value of the size of
                # the compressed img.
                size = int.from_bytes(size_msg, byteorder='big')
            temp_pixels = recvall(size, udp_conn, max_bytes)
            try:
                pixels = decompress(temp_pixels)
                scrn_img = pygame.image.fromstring(pixels, (950, 500), 'RGB')
                scrn_shot = pygame.transform.scale(scrn_img, (950, 500))
                # putting the screenshot on pygame screen
                screen.blit(scrn_shot, (0, 0))
                pygame.display.flip()
                clock.tick(60)
            except:
                pass
        except:
            pass
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                        pygame.quit()
                        sys.exit()'''
```

The pygame screen starts at full screen, then resizes and crashes... And I have no idea why. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think the for loop for events is in the except block Check indentation and try again

**That's nice**
And Try updating your code from this to this

```
max_bytes = 64000
udp_conn = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
udp_conn.bind(('0.0.0.0', 5000))
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1900, 1000))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
while True:
    try:
        size_msg, address = udp_conn.recvfrom(max_bytes)
        size = int.from_bytes(size_msg, byteorder='big')
        while size > 10000000:  # if size is greater than 10M then loop has to fire to get value of the size of
            # the compressed img.
            size = int.from_bytes(size_msg, byteorder='big')
        temp_pixels = recvall(size, udp_conn, max_bytes)
        try:
            pixels = decompress(temp_pixels)
            scrn_img = pygame.image.fromstring(pixels, (950, 500), 'RGB')
            scrn_shot = pygame.transform.scale(scrn_img, (950, 500))
            # putting the screenshot on pygame screen
            screen.blit(scrn_shot, (0, 0))
            pygame.display.flip()
            clock.tick(60)
        except:
            pass
    except:
        pass
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
```

**To This**

```
max_bytes = 64000
udp_conn = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
udp_conn.bind(('0.0.0.0', 5000))
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1900, 1000))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
while True:
    try:
        size_msg, address = udp_conn.recvfrom(max_bytes)
        size = int.from_bytes(size_msg, byteorder='big')
        while size > 10000000:  # if size is greater than 10M then loop has to fire to get value of the size of
            # the compressed img.
            size = int.from_bytes(size_msg, byteorder='big')
        temp_pixels = recvall(size, udp_conn, max_bytes)
        try:
            pixels = decompress(temp_pixels)
            scrn_img = pygame.image.fromstring(pixels, (950, 500), 'RGB')
            scrn_shot = pygame.transform.scale(scrn_img, (950, 500))
        except:
            pass
    except:
        pass
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
    # putting the screenshot on pygame screen
    screen.blit(scrn_shot, (0, 0))
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
```

This is because the updating should happen on every frame and not only when you are loading the image.
And for this to work you should probably declare a default value to the `scrn_shot` variable.
And also add `screen.fill((COLOR_IN_RGB))` Above the `screen.blit` this would fill the screen with black color every frame.

***And your Program should be working.***

Comment: Hi! I didn't notice that, I guess 4 eyes are better than 2... Changed it and moved it to the start of the while true loop, still freezes up when opened.